# azure Export db fail. The storage account cannot be accessed. Please check the storage account name and key and try again

Tags: azure

I built a storage account according to some youtube video and trying to export my database on azure. My aim was to export it and transform to .mdf and .ldf.
But i fail export it.
the message shows:
The storage account cannot be accessed. Please check the storage account name and key and try again

could anyone help me? or i should just pay for the support? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

> message shows: The storage account cannot be accessed. Please check the storage account name and key and try again

Microsoft does not allow to export data from SQL on Azure to an Azure Storage account with firewall enabled.

- **Storage behind a firewall is currently not supported.**

Ensure the public network access enabled from all networks to access SQL database.

[image]

you can get access key from **your storage account >> Security + networking >> acess key**

Ensure the public network access is allowed for selected networks to access storage account.

[image]

***Exported database succesfully:***

[image]
[image]

Comment: The network access are enabled but it still fails. Are there any other possibilities? thank you